# jacoco + tomcat = jacoco.exec, Reporting zero coverage. Help. 

Tags: tomcat, jacoco

I have a web application deployed on Tomcat. Before I get into further details let me spell out the versions.

Versions: jdk 1.7, Tomcat - 7.0.19, jacoco -0.5.6

I have added jdk1.7 to Tomcat. In \apache-tomcat-7.0.19\bin\startup.bat file I have added.

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0
```

Also I have added jacoco agent to Tomcat. In apache-tomcat-7.0.19\bin\catalina.bat I have added.

```
SET JACOCO=-javaagent:<my download folder>\jacoco-0.5.6.201201232323\lib\jacocoagent.jar=destfile=C:\jacoco.exec,append=true,includes=* 
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %JACOCO%
```

Now, when I fire up Tomcat, and hit my web applications, as expected there is a C:\jacoco.exec file.

I have now moved the code to the following directory structure 
 
 jacoco.exec
 /bin/
 /coveragereport

Now I have used the class ReportGenerator from http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/examples/java/ReportGenerator.java. I have got a bunch of reports in HTML format in the /coveragereport directory. However, all code is being shown as non touched. Although after I have fired up Tomcat I had gone to the http://localhost:/ and browsed around. I was hoping to get a coverage percentage reported.

I am missing something very basic. Help please.

Answer (score 8):

Tomcat will write the Jacoco file on shutdown.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can use the [ant dump task](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html):

```
jacoco:dump address="server.example.com" reset="true" destfile="remote.exec"/>
```

But for that to work, you have to specify the `output mode tcpserver` for the [java agent](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html).

```
-javaagent:[yourpath/]jacocoagent.jar=output=tcpserver,address=<host>,port=<port>,...
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the suggested way (tcpserver), I'm using JAcoco 0.6.2+. I don't see any server bound to the default port 6300. When I run the dump command, I get "Unable to dump coverage data", with "Connection Refused", because there's nothing running on that port. Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: @MarcellodeSales i'm also facing this issue... where I could be mistaken?

Comment: @MarcellodeSales it is a long time ago, but it is crucial to have output=tcpserver defined. and maybe set your own ports via address=<host>,port=<port>

Comment: Wow, I'm glad this is still active... I'm using Gradle and 2 years ago I god something working... I would post it here if I still had the setup...

Answer (score 1):

6300 is a default port provided. You can change the port or you can look for the free ports which can be listened using `netstat -an | grep "LISTEN"`